Pathloss of UV-C radiation on water
I'm studying the design of an UV-C projector to be used in underwater environment.
One of the first parameter I need to evaluate is the distance from the UV-C source to the target surface (that will be underwater of course).
The projector source has a 260nm wavelength and a radiant flux of about 100mW.
I found several articles about the light spectrum absorbance by water but diagrams are not so detailed/clear to allow any calculations.
I have only figured out that the absorption rate of UV-C should be of the same level of the red/IR radiation.
Moreover I don't know if I can use an RF path loss equation (mostly because is used in air) to get the result I need.
How can I estimate maximum distance per radiated power or how much source power is needed to reach a target at a given distance with a certain radiation margin?
P.S. reading some other SE questions I found I need to specify that  I'm talking about sea-water (since it seems that conductivity plays a role ... this seems to exclude I can use RF path loss equation)
--- EDIT ---


UV radiation is not RF radiation, UV wavelength is many times smaller than macroscopic obstacles, so UV radiation propagates almost in straight lines(if no scattering). Its intensity decreases due to several effects: beam divergence (intensity would decrease with distance as $1/x^2$), absorption and scattering (intensity would decrease as $e^{-\alpha x}$ - Lambert-Beer law). Sometimes you can ignore beam divergence (if distance is short enough) and then you can make do with the simple Lambert-Beer law. You need to find $\alpha$ appropriate for UV radiation with 260nm wavelength, in salt water.

ok thnx... I looked around and found that the $k_\lambda$ in salt water should be around $0.5 m^{-1}$

so if the distance between source and target is about 1m
, the source radiation intensity is 1
the target incident radiation intensity should be around 0.6
. Correct? Or I'm missing something?
